# int array[10] = {1 , 2, 0, 3} . How can I find out that there are 4 elements here? I know how to find the size of array

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I tried this code..As you can see the problem is the empty elements are zero. So, I tried to check with it but the thing is I can have 0 as an element.

````
int main()
{
    int array[10] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4};

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(array)/ sizeof(*array)); // This is the size of array

    int i = 0;

    while(array[i] != 0  && i < 10) {
        i++;
    };

    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `int numelems = 0; for (int i = 0; i < sizeof array/sizeof *array; i++) if (array[i]) numelems++; printf("%d elements <> zero\n", numelems);`

Comment: You need to track the number of valid element by other means (extra variable?). Or use a value that cannot be a valid element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the array to a number outside the range of your inputs. Like a negative number.

```
for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    array[i] = -1;
```

or set it to `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `int array[10]` will always create an array of 10 elements and you can't ask the compiler which of them have been assigned.

What you could do is `int array[] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4}` then the compiler will infer the number of elements for you and you'll have `sizeof(array)/ sizeof(*array) == 5`

Answer (score 0):

> int array[10] = {1 , 2, 0, 3} . How can I find out that there are 4 elements here?

How can you say there are 4 elements there as you declared that `int array[10]` with the size of 10 elements. This implies, you already know the no. of elements. Also, in this scenario, you can't use an `if` statement to determine the no. of elements as you probably know that in C, if you initialize an array of 10 elements with less than 10 values, rest of them will automatically be assigned to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You know how many elements are in the initializer, so you create another variable that stores that number:

   ```
   int array[10] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4};
   int num_items = 5;
   ```

   You'll need to update `num_items` as you "add" or "remove" items to the array.  If you treat the array as a stack (only add or remove at the highest index), then this is easy-ish:

   ```
   array[num_items++] = 7; // adds 7 after 4
   ...
   x = array[--num_items]; // x gets 7, 7 is "removed" from the array, need special
                           // case logic for element 0
   ```

   You pick a value that *isn't* valid (say `-1`) and initialize the remaining elements explicitly:

   ```
   int array[10] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
   ```

   You size the array for the initializer, meaning it can only ever store that many elements:

   ```
   int array[] = {1, 2, 0, 3, 4};
   ```

Otherwise, you'll need to use a different data structure (such as a linked list) if you need a container that can grow or shrink as items are added or removed.